# How to get a working Catalyst Center?

Tags: ati

I've installed AMD drivers using the Additional Driver utility, but I am unable to get the Catalyst Control Center to launch - after I input my password, no other window comes up.

Additional detail:
This is a ZBook 14, so the graphics are a hybrid Intel® HD Graphics 4400 & AMD FirePro™ M4100.

Doing `sudo amdcccle` from the terminal does launch it, but I'd like the Unity launcher option to work properly.

Comment: What is your graphics card, and Ubuntu Version?

Comment: If you start it from a terminal, is there any error message?

Comment: What happens when you execute `amdxdg-su -c gnome-terminal`?

Comment: It does the same thing and it actually quickly flashes a message which I was able to read this time - 'Authentication failure'. However my user password is correct and works for everything else. Here's a screencast of what happens: http://ge.tt/3rIxNsq1/v/0

Answer (score 0):

Run this to update fglrx update

```
sudo apt-get install -y fglrx-updates
```

Run this command to open Catalyst Control Centre as Administrator.

```
gksu amdcccle
```

Comment: I'd like to be able to use the option provided in the launcher and not have to drop down to the terminal.

Comment: I am guessing you are using ubuntu 14.04. Please follow the instructions descried below - 
Press on windows button or find out Search panel from your unity launcher. Search there typing "AMD Catalyst Control Centre". You should find it there. 

If not working then -

 - Open File Manager 
 - Enter **Computer** Named partition
 - Enter **usr > share > applications**
 - You will find all your installed Apps there.

Hope it will solve your problem. :)

Comment: Hey, yeah, I am on 14.04. The normal one launches OK - it is the one with admin privs that doesn't.